# servicebus messagecount check returns true even though it's 0

Tags: azure, boolean-logic, servicebus

I have a function that checks if there is still a message in my servicebus which it constantly checks.

The function that gets the ammount is:

```
    public int GetActiveMessageCount()
    {
        var connectionString = azureConnectionStringWithoutEntityPath;
        long messageCount = 0;
        try
        {
            var nameSpaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
            messageCount = nameSpaceManager.GetQueue(azureQueueName).MessageCountDetails.ActiveMessageCount;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }

        return (int)messageCount;
    }
```

And the check is:

```
    public bool MessageCountBiggerThenZero()
    {
        int messageCount = 0;
        try
        {
            messageCount = this.GetActiveMessageCount();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("An error occured while checking if the messageValue is bigger then zero and not null saying : " + e);
        }
        return messageCount > 0;
    }
```

this works perfectly in the beginning when there are zero messages but after it starts receiving messages and then passes the last messsage it still passes the MessageCountBiggerThenZero check.

Does anyone know how this can be? Does the serviceBus return other values after it's last message?

Edit:

More insight into the check (So it still passes the if statement even if there is no message anymore):

```
public object RecieveOneMessageFromServiceBus()
    {
        var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(azureConnectionString);
        BrokeredMessage brokermessage = null;
        client.PrefetchCount = 1; // get 1 message at a time
        if (MessageCountBiggerThenZero())
        {
            try
            {
                 // try to recieve message
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Where are you invoking `MessageCountBiggerThenZero` method, could you provide the code about receiving messages and invoking the MessageCountBiggerThenZero check?

Comment: @Bruce-MSFT i added the code to the question. I use it also in other places but they have the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I seem to have fixed it but I have no clue how and why. I did implement it as Bruce says but this did not work. Maybe the complete method was not send fast enough or something else is going one but now I changed my receiving method to receive and delete and added a timer for getting the message of about 5 seconds like:

```
 var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(azureConnectionString,ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);

brokermessage = client.Receive(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

With this code it seems to work and anyone able to explain me why would be very much wanted.

Edit:

See comment below for extra explanation on how to implement this better

Comment: Does the `RecieveOneMessageFromServiceBus` method would run in multi-thread? I assumed that one instance call `MessageCountBiggerThenZero` checking while the last message is received with `PeekLock` mode in another instance before calling `complete`. I would prefer to using `QueueClient.OnMessage` for receiving queue messages.

Comment: Correct. This has probably been it. will change code afterwards to fit my needs more after.

Comment: Since my reply could not reproduce this issue, you could update your reply with more details and mark it as an acceptable answer for other community who could encounter the same issue.

Comment: i will. i can do that in a few hours. it's still the only explanation there is.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, I assumed that you do not invoke [BrokeredMessage.Complete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.complete?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_BrokeredMessage_Complete) which could mark the message as processed and deleted after your have handled the message. I modified your code and add logs to print the current active messages as follows:

```
public static object RecieveOneMessageFromServiceBus()
{
    var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(azureConnectionString);
    client.PrefetchCount = 1; // get 1 message at a time
    if (MessageCountBiggerThenZero())
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("begin retrieving a message...");
            var message = client.Receive();
            Console.WriteLine($"received message with MessageId:{message.MessageId}");

            //after receive the message for handling
            Console.WriteLine($"after received a message in processing, active messages count:{GetActiveMessageCount()}");

            //after handled the message
            message.Complete();

            Console.WriteLine($"invoke message.Complete() to complete the received message");

            //after receive the message for handling
            Console.WriteLine($"after Complete() the message, active messages count:{GetActiveMessageCount()}");
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

[image]

Also, you could log into the Azure Portal and check the **ACTIVE MESSAGE COUNT** under the Overview of your Service Bus queue as follows:

[image]

Additionally, you could follow the official tutorial about [Receive messages from the queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues#4-receive-messages-from-the-queue) without checking the current active messages by yourself, aslo you could refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40596942/azure-service-bus-receive-messages-with-onmessage-method).

Comment: Hey Bruce unfortunately I do mark it as complete. As I said it all goes perfect until I complete the last message. At that moment I have for example read 40 messages without a single problem but when I reach the 0 active message the MessageCountBiggerThenZero() function still says there is a message in there indicating a true boolean

Comment: After you completed the last message, have you checked the **ACTIVE MESSAGE COUNT** on Azure Portal?

Comment: yes and the function also does this immediatly with : this.GetActiveMessageCount();

Comment: That's strange...if the message has been completed successfully, the active message count would be zero. I assumed that you could try to double-check the message count. Additionally, are you sure you have checked the active messages count on Azure Portal??

Comment: yea hence the question how this is possible. I did check the azure portal and even checkt it by hand by using written code which i check every step since my code does this about every second and it might go to fast.

Next to that i checked the azure portal but that is not really updated real-time but still the same result.