# Azure service hub automatically receive message in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, azure, azureservicebus

I'm very new in Azure. Is there any way to receive messages from queue/topic automatically instead of making some kind of cron mechanism which will be making requests for new messages? This kind of functionality is available in RabbitMQ client.

Comment: You should look at the documentation prior to posting a question like this.

Comment: I was looking in docs and I didnt found answer.  @Mikhail sad that Javascript SDK does not support that. It was my mistake to not mention that I was looking for js solution.

Comment: No worries. Yes, mentioning what SDK the question is for or tagging it appropriately changes the context drastically. JS support is not as good as .NET or Java. The only [comment in documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-nodejs-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions) is exactly what you're basking. Sadly, never answered. I would suggest to [raise it with the ASB team](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues) to clarify the route JavaScript SDK is going to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit vague... In C# SDK there is `OnMessage` callback that you can sign up to, see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.onmessage?view=azure-dotnet) and [a full example in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40597643/1171619).

For a fully automated serverless way of handling messages, have a look at [Azure Functions Service Bus Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus). It's based on [WebJobs SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Service-Bus) which you could use directly in self-hosted apps.

Comment: Thanks but there is any equivalent way to make it in javascript? This is what am looking for and I can't find it in docs.

Comment: I don't think JavaScript SDK supports that... JS is supported in Azure Functions though.

Comment: ```serviceBusService``` from azure-sb package have method ```receiveSubscriptionMessage```. What do you think about 'cron like' solution to call this method for maybe every 5 seconds ? It is good way ? Or better will be create .NET service which will be calling for example  SignalR to recieve messages in JS ?